# Compiler runtime error after switching solution to VS 2010

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

we switched recently our asp.net 3.5 solution from VS 2008 to VS 2010 while still wanting it to be in .net 3.5 (as the deployment server runs on 3.5 only)

The libraries are ok, but the web site is causing us problems. The error message we get on every aspx page is like this:

```
D:\WebSites\.....aspx: ASP.NET runtime error: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem2' from assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

I found out that the interface the compiler is looking for (ITaskItem2) is only available in .net 4.0, but it keeps looking for it in 3.5 assembly which is obviously wrong.

We were trying to locate where this discrepancy is originating, but with no luck.

It hinders our work significantly, because the intellisense is not working for asp components, also debugging of the web pages is not working.

But even when this error occurs in VS, the pages work ok when displaying them in browser (using IIS), so this is VS-only problem.

If you have any idea, what could be wrong here, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I managed to get things right after lots of experimenting.

The solution was to let the VS generate new standard web.config for web site and adding the few extra options we are using into it..

There are only 2 differences between the old and new web.config:

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
```

was changed to

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.50727" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
```

Not sure if this affects something.

But what seems more important, in the non-working web.config there was one additional section in `<runtime>`:

```
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Framework"
       publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
```

I am not a web.config guru and I do not see what's wrong with the provided section, but without it the things started to work miraculously.